# How to update sensors info

Tags: 12.10, sensors, lm-sensors

I have an ASrock 880GM-LE FX motherboard with an AMD 8350 cpu.  I set up sensors by saying Y to everything and now when I run sensors I get

```
w83627dhg-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:        +0.91 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:          +0.00 V  (min =  +1.78 V, max =  +0.50 V)  ALARM
AVCC:         +3.36 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:        +3.36 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:          +1.68 V  (min =  +1.97 V, max =  +1.78 V)  ALARM
in5:          +1.70 V  (min =  +2.03 V, max =  +0.48 V)  ALARM
in6:          +1.86 V  (min =  +1.90 V, max =  +0.89 V)  ALARM
3VSB:         +3.46 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:         +3.42 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.30 V)  ALARM
fan1:           0 RPM  (min = 1506 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan2:        2860 RPM  (min = 1430 RPM, div = 8)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min = 1506 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan5:           0 RPM  (min = 1506 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
temp1:        +43.0°C  (high = -103.0°C, hyst = +91.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +40.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +32.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
intrusion0:  ALARM

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +21.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +67.0°C)

fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:       32.21 W  (crit = 125.19 W)
```

I have

```
sensors --version
sensors version 3.3.1 with libsensors version 3.3.1
```

How can I update the information sensors is using to get something more informative as its output?

Comment: What do you mean by more informative? Do you want to see information about the video card as well?

Comment: I don't get your actual question either. You also seem to have a lot more information than I am able to see on most systems. For example it's very rare to see a desktop computer reporting its power usage! Wish I could do that!

Comment: It would be nice to have names for temp1, temp2, temp3 and fan2 . In fact fan2 is my CPU fan but I don't know what the temp measurements are. Also there are ALARMs for in1, in4,in5,in6 and Vbat (I don't know what they mean) which I am assuming are mistakes in some config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every model of hardware using this chip is different and it's hard to tell from software which reported fan speed is connected to what fan in your case. `lm-sensors` is just concerned about the chip responsible for providing this data and displaying this in a sane way.

#### Change labels and ignore entries

However, it's possible to change the labels and entries listed to match your situation properly. Create a sensors configuration file in `/etc/sensors.d/`, e.g. `mypc.conf` and include this:

```
chip "w83627dhg-isa-0290"

  ignore fan1
  label fan2 "CPU fan"
  ignore fan3
  ignore fan5
```

After saving this file, the output of `sensors` should be changed accordingly. The current system default configuration can be found in `/etc/sensors3.conf`. Please don't modify this file as you're supposed to override any values in your own files in the `.d` directory.

#### Changing ranges for ALARMs

If you feel that the reported values as `ALARM` are within a safe range, you can change that as well. From the `sensors3.conf` file I see that `Vbat` is actually `in8` and defined with 10% margin. If you wish to change this, override this as well to become 15% like this:

```
  set in3_min 3.3 * 0.85
  set in3_max 3.3 * 1.15
```

---

I hope this will get you somewhere in changing the configuration to a point that it's actually useful for your set up! For more information on what you can do in the configuration file, see the manpage: `man 5 sensors.conf`.

Comment: Thanks. Even with the motherboard manual ftp://europe.asrock.com/manual/880GM-LE%20FX.pdf it's not at all obvious to me how to work out what temp1, temp2 and temp3 are. In particular, the motherboard manual implies it has only two temperature sensors it seems!  http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/VoltageLabelsAndScaling may be useful for the voltage part...

Comment: @Raphael Yeah, such information is usually not very well documented. The only reliable readings are usually only provided using the proprietary tool provided by the mainboard manufacturer (in Windows). Since this is really mainboard type specific, it's hard to get the right information in an answer here (we have different hardware!).

Comment: OK. I actually have that dvd in my hand currently but as you say, it's not obvious what to do with it in linux.